# Conversation API call

Tags: java, android-studio, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377926/watson-conversation-cannot-execute-servicecall) as reference on building my Conversation bot but i stumble upon one single error. ie; System.out.println is not working. I am getting this :Please help on how to remove this. Thanks in advance.

[image] 
[image]

My Imports:
[image: Imports]

Comment: System object is core language. Did you create your own System class? What does your import list say?

Comment: Yes, I have created my own system class. The imports I have included as image in my original question, Please see. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`response.getText` returns `List<String>` not `String` so this is not compatible. What you can do is

```
for(String s:response.getText()){
System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Antoniossss for the solution, but it doesnot seem to help. System.out.<println> is not even there in my dropdown. Please see my newly added iamge in my original question. Thanks